# Why am I getting OutOfMemory exceptions when I have plenty of memory?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, out-of-memory

I have a program (Fractal10) that executes a loop where the number of iterations depends on a parameter I set manually. When the number of iterations is small the program runs fine. When the number of iterations is large I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$Fractal10>.$Program' threw an exception. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

I am running Windows 10 Professional with 16 GB of memory and 25600 MB of virtual memory on an Intel Haswell processor and the latest version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. After the exception is thrown, the Task Manager shows the following:

```
Memory: 64%
Fractal10 (32 bit)L 1,719.2 MB # this is the culprit
Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (32 bit): 822.7 MB
... # other apps
```

Why am I getting this error when only 64% of memory has been used? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: That is 84% of the 2GB address space available to a 32-bit process.  You can never reach 100%, allocations fail before that when they can't find enough contiguous memory.  Forcing your program to run in 32-bit mode when you have a 64-bit OS and that much RAM is not useful.  So just remove the forcing, Project > Properties > Build tab, untick "Prefer 32-bit".  But it won't hurt to dig some more, computing fractal curves should not require that much memory.  Forgetting to call Dispose() on a bitmap object is a traditional oversight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, is your OS 32 or 64bit? If it's the former, you won't actually have access to all of the installed memory.

Additionally, (and I'm assuming you're using the .Net framework, correct me if I'm wrong) you'll need to set your platform target to x64 inside your build configuration. On top of this, you can add the following config to your app.config file:

`<runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
</runtime>`

This will allow traversal of objects greater than 2GB.

Comment: Setting the target to x64 solved the memory problem but the program runs about 1/3 slower. It is a big difference. Is there a way to make it run as fast in 64-bit as in 32-bit?

Comment: @Soldalma that's a pretty generic question. You would need to profile the program and find your bottleneck, e.g. is some algorithm too slow? Are you using the most efficient data structures?  is there too much memory allocated and just too much GC-ing? Etc... Run the profiler on VS on it. In my experience the bottlenecks tend to be quite unintuitive...

Comment: Ok, but why would the same program run in 2.5 minutes when compiled with 64 bits and 1.5 minutes when compiled with 32 bits? Do the bottlenecks create more problems under 64 bit compilation?

Comment: I agree here, I think some profiling needs to be done. Computationally, your program should not bottleneck on a higher bit rate system.

Comment: @Soldalma what you are observing is specific to your case, and cannot be generalized. for computation intensive code, I'd expect 64-bit perform better, but for memory intensive code you might observe cases where 64-bit is slower, could be due to many issues, one example of just using more memory, doing more GC, not fitting into cache etc. Are you compiling everything in release mode with optimizations turned on? Either way, profile. :-) It's fun.

Answer (score 4):

You should use 64 bit versions of your software if you intend to use more than ~1,8 GB of memory.